# `UIVisualEffectView` with blur alters hue and makes image darker or lighter - how to fix?

Tags: uikit, blur, uivisualeffectview

I would like `UIVisualEffectView` to just give me **gaussian blur** without any lightening or darkening. But [UIBlurEffect.Style](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiblureffect/style) only has styles that alter the image in some way.

How can I achieve that without using `CIImageFilter`, `vImageBoxConvolve_ARGB8888` and raw CoreGraphics whatsoever, just purely with `UIVisualEffectView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to achieve this using CoreAnimation.